# Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

my problem is that when user go live and have live status on discord, in console i get error "
TypeError: Cannot read property 'activities' of undefined" and bot is crashing. I expect to bot send a message with link to stream.
Discord.js - v12
Code:

```
    client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const channel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "test");
    if (!channel) return;
        let oldStreamingStatus = oldMember.presence.activities.type ? oldMember.presence.activities.streaming : false;
        let newStreamingStatus = newMember.presence.activities.type ? newMember.presence.activities.streaming : false;
  if(oldStreamingStatus == newStreamingStatus){
    return;
  }

  if(newStreamingStatus){
    if(message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "test")) {
        channel.send(`${newMember.user}, is live URL: ${newMember.presence.activities.url} ${newMember.presence.activities.name}`);
    return; 
  }else
  return;
}});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`oldMember` and `newMember` are of type [`Presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence), so you do not need to access the `.presence` property to get the member's activities, you can simply use `oldMember.activities`. For `newMember.presence.activities.url` & `newMember.presence.activities.name` do this:

```js
newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING').name
newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING').url
```

Either way however, your code won't work, since `activities` returns an array of [`Activity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity) so you can go about doing this in 2 ways.

**(Recommended)** Looking for `Activity` of type `STREAMING`:

```js
let oldStreamingStatus = oldMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
let newStreamingStatus = newMember.activities.find(activity => activity.type === 'STREAMING') ? true : false;
```

Getting the first `Activity`:

```js
let oldStreamingStatus = oldMember.activities[0].type === 'STREAMING' ? true : false
let newStreamingStatus = newMember.activities[0].type === 'STREAMING' ? true : false
```

Comment: Can you tell me why in bot message url and stream name are undefined? ` channel.send(` ${newMember.user}, is live URL: ${newMember.activities.url} ${newMember.activities.name}`); even when i change activities to activity i get error Cannot read property 'url' of undefined.

Comment: No problem, but if i can have one more question - So i want to send message by bot only when user have certain role so i make: const roleid = '706528765009985576';    if(newMember.roles.has(roleid)) ... ; and i get error 
Cannot read property 'has' of undefined; how can i fix it?

Comment: As we already established `newMember` returns a `Presence` not a `User` or a `GuildMember` so you need to do the following: `newMember.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === roleid)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that oldMember and newMember are already presences, so remove `.presence`.

Comment: It helped but still bot don't send a message.

Comment: This is bcause activities is array. So you can use @Syntle solution, but idk why there is the ? true : false in second example, because === returns true/false

Comment: It will be good idea to first look on the documentation before asking: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities